# How to make do not auto session out? In zendframework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-session

In my application.ini i do not have anything special. And i have tried as following in my Bootstrap.php, but it never worked, i get always session out auto. My goal is once a user loges in, he should be able to stay alive for unlimited session unless he press logout.

The application is used in Call center. Everytime they want to pick the call, the session is automatically out. So i have to stop it. But how can i do this?

```
/**
 * My session
 */
//Zend_Session::rememberMe(60);   << did not worked
//Zend_Session::rememberMe(864000); << did not worked
Zend_Session::start();

$mysession = new Zend_Session_Namespace('mysession');
if (isset($mysession->rows['group'])) 
 {
  $view->member =  $mysession->rows;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$mysession->setExpirationSeconds(864000, 'rows');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this also:

```
    Zend_Session::start();
    Zend_Session::rememberMe(864000); // one day session
    $mysession = new Zend_Session_Namespace();
    $mysession->setExpirationSeconds(864000);
```